# Probabilities in an Eclectic Golf Competition

Tags: probability

An Eclectic golf competition is one where you count your best score at each hole over several rounds.

Assume the probability of taking a certain number of shots over (or under) par at a particular hole is p(x), x = 1 to 8 (say) is known (and for simplicity, is the same for all holes)

Then what is the probability that the best score at a particular hole after n rounds is x?

Simulation would be the easy answer but there must be an approach via probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the random variable representing the number of shots *below* par. We have to find the last and largest [order statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) of the sample obtained by playing a hole $n$ times, or sampling $n$ times from $X$.

Let $f(x)$ be the pmf of $X$ and $F(x)$ the corresponding CDF. Then by [the same Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Dealing_with_discrete_variables) I linked above, the probability that the best score at a particular hole after $n$ rounds is $x$ works out as
$$\begin{align}P(X_{(n)}=x)&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-n}\binom nj((1-F(x))^j(F(x))^{n-j}-(1-F(x)+f(x))^j(F(x)-f(x))^{n-j})\\
&=(F(x))^n-(F(x)-f(x))^n\end{align}$$
This answer does not depend on the distribution of $X$ itself or even its support; it only matters that $X$ is discrete.

Comment: Wow. Thanks.  I may have to sit in a dark room with a wet towel over my head to figure out what this means!  I have some stats somewhere from which I can estimate f(x) - maybe I'll have a play this Autumn/Winter. Thanks again